# Wrap words in text which match words in array and add unique class name

Tags: javascript

I have some text:

"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam porta porttitor ultricies. Nullam blandit nulla vitae ullamcorper egestas. Maecenas dui orci, elementum non ipsum in, elementum pulvinar fermentum risus. Proin at enim porttitor, congue metus condimentum, lacinia nisi. Nam ac nisl diam. Nullam elementum purus eget risus hendrerit vulputate."

I have list of words which i want to wrap in text with

example words:

```
words = [
    elementum : 'class1',
    pulvinar : 'class2',
    lacinia : 'class3'
]
```

Also each wrapped word must have unique data-attribute it.

Result text must looks something like that

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam porta
porttitor ultricies. Nullam blandit nulla vitae ullamcorper egestas. 
Maecenas dui orci, 
<span class="class1" data-id="132123">elementum</span> non ipsum 
in, <span class="class1" data-id="1344000">elementum</span>
<span class="class2" data-id="1344030">pulvinar</span> fermentum risus.
Proin at enim porttitor, congue metus condimentum, <span class="class3" data-id="1344000">lacinia</span> nisi. Nam ac nisl diam. 
Nullam elementum purus eget risus hendrerit vulputate.
```

Update: i can use regex but how for each replaced word i can unique data-id (some random string), because some words can be twice in text.

Comment: If you haven't made an attempt, consider making one and then come back if you can't figure it out on your own. If you *have* made an attempt, edit your question to include it. Right now it sounds like you're just asking us to code this for you.

Comment: I asking  for starting point. I can split text by split() but i don't think that this is best way for do that, with replace() also i can't do that. Regex ?

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the words using a regexp for each word:

```js
const string = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam porta porttitor ultricies. Nullam blandit nulla vitae ullamcorper egestas. Maecenas dui orci, elementum non ipsum in, elementum pulvinar fermentum risus. Proin at enim porttitor, congue metus condimentum, lacinia nisi. Nam ac nisl diam. Nullam elementum purus eget risus hendrerit vulputate.';
const classMap = [
  ['elementum', 'class1'],
  ['pulvinar', 'class2'],
  ['lacinia', 'class3']
];

const wrapped = classMap.reduce((wrapped, [word, className]) => {
  return wrapped.replace(
    new RegExp(`(${word})`, 'g'), 
    `<span class="${className}">$1</span>`
  );
}, string);

console.log(wrapped);
```

Comment: But there biggest problem for me is: if i have to same words on text twice (or more) i need add unique timestamp as data-id  (or id), i can figureout how add this